# Is it possible to sync recurring events from Google calendar to Salesforce?

Tags: event, calendar, google, einstein-activity-capture

I am trying to sync my Google calendar to Salesforce, but the recurring events from Google are not coming through to Salesforce. I've tried with both Lightning Sync and Einstein Activity Capture. According to [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_productivity_eac_google_recurring_events.htm&release=246&type=5), Salesforce released this capability in Winter '24 with Einstein Activity Capture. However, I can't see the 'Sync event series' checkbox mentioned in the article when I set up the sync configuration. Here is what I can see in **Setup > Einstein Activity Capture > Settings**
[image: Einstein Event configuration options]

[This documentation from Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.aac_event_sync_event_series.htm&type=5) also suggests I should be able to sync recurring events from google. Am I interpreting the release notes from Salesforce incorrectly? Is anyone aware of a way to successfully sync recurring events from Google to Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that event series sync is **only available when the sync direction is Google Suite -> Salesforce**.

I had originally interpreted the documentation to mean that *recurring events* can only be synced from Google, but "normal" one-time events could still be synced both directions. Unfortunately, this is not the case. You have to choose between a two-direction sync and getting recurring events from Google.